# Is this an example of a livelock or deadlock or starvation?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, deadlock, livelock, starvation

Scheduling Scheme : Preemptive Priority Scheduling

Situation :

A process L (Low priority) acquires a spinlock on a resource (R). While still in the Critical Section, L gets preempted because of the arrival of another process - H (Higher Priority) into the ready queue. .

However, H also needs to access resource R and so tries to acquire a spin lock which results in H going to busy wait. Because spinlocks are used, H never actually goes into Wait and will always be in Running state or Ready state (in case an even higher priority process arrives ready queue), preventing L or any process with a priority lower than H from ever executing.

A) All processes with priority less than H can be considered to be under Starvation

B) All processes with priority less than H as well as the process H, can be considered to be in a deadlock. [But, then don't the processes have to be in Wait state for the system to be considered to be in a deadlock?]

C) All processes with priority less than H as well as the process H, can be considered to be in a livelock.[But, then only the state of H changes constantly, all the low priority process remain in just the Ready state. Don't the state of all processes need to change (as part of a spin lock) continuously if the system in livelock?]

D) H alone can be considered to be in livelock, all lower priority processes are just under starvation, not in livelock.

E) H will not progress, but cannot be considered to be in livelock. All lower priority processes are just under starvation, not in livelock.

Which of the above statements are correct? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a livelock, because definition of livelock requires that ["states of the processes involved in the livelock constantly change with regard to one another"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Livelock), and here states effectively do not change.

The first process can be considered to be in processor starvation, because if there were additional processor, it could run on it and eventually release the lock and let the second processor to run.

The situation also can be considered as a deadlock, with 2 resources in the resource graph, and 2 processes attempting to acquire that resources in opposite directions: first process owns the lock and needs the processor to proceed, while the second process owns the processor and needs the lock to proceed.